# Using a Google Script to populate dynamic dropdown menus in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with my first Google Script. I have a range of dropdown menus that display a list of items from my Google Sheets doc which work perfectly.

The menus display a list of either media types, brands or widths. My script removes any duplicates, sorts them out alphabetically and allows me to choose the column by name.

I'm now trying to make those dropdown menus dynamic. When the user selects a media type from the first menu, only the brands for that media type show in the second menu. When the user selects the brand, only the widths show for that media type and brand in the third menu. If the row has a matching laminate, the laminate question will appear. I then finally add a quantity and a price will display.

Here's what my sheets look like:

[image]

Here's how my dropdown menus are currently setup (each colName is changed to match the type of items I want but in general, all my drop downs are coded exactly the same). They all work as expected apart from linking to each other.

First dropdown menu

```
function getTypes() { 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456").getSheetByName("v-prices");

  const colName = 'Media Type';
  const colNum = getTypeColNumByName(colName);
  if (colNum === null) {
    Logger.log('Column ' + colName + ' was not found!');
    return [];
  }

  const firstRow = 2;
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get all values from column
  const columnData = sheet.getRange(firstRow, colNum, lastRow).getValues().flat();

  // filter values on duplicates
  return columnData.filter((el, i) => i === columnData.indexOf(el) && el !== '').sort()
}

function getTypeColNumByName(colName, row = 1) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456").getSheetByName("v-prices");
  
  const [data] = sheet.getRange(row, 1, row, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const col = data.indexOf(colName);

  // adding 1 because column nums starting from 1
  return col === -1 ? null : col + 1;
}
```

That works as it should.

How can I make the second menu link to the first. How do I make the first menu link to the first and second etc etc?

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pricing Calculator</h1>
    <?var url = getUrl();?>
    <form method="post" action="<?= url ?>" >
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Company Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>
    
      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Please select your media type?</label><br>
      <select name="type" style="font-size: 20px">
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= types[i] ?>" ><?= types[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Please choose your brand?</label><br>
      <select name="brand" style="font-size: 20px">
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < brands.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= brands[i] ?>" ><?= brands[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Please select your media width?</label><br>
      <select name="width" style="font-size: 20px">
      <option value="" ></option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= widths[i] ?>" ><?= widths[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      <p>Do you want to laminate the print?</p>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gloss-laminate" name="gloss-laminate">
        <label for="gloss-laminate">Gloss Laminate</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gloss-laminate" name="gloss-laminate">
        <label for="gloss-laminate">Matt Laminate</label>
      </div><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >Quantity</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <label style="font-size: 20px" >How many hours?</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" style="font-size: 20px" /><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save Quote" style="font-size: 20px" /> 
      <span style="font-size: 20px" ><?= message ?></span>      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will probably have to tie it to the onChange event of the first.  So you cannot do it with scriptlets.  You'll have to make a call to the server to get the data and return it to the Success Handler.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your Google Apps Script and HTML. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?